# Percentage above a number in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table that shows how many seconds the customer was in line to be served, in seconds.

I need to put together a query that shows how many percent of chats were served within 30 seconds.

I was only able to count the number of calls over the ideal period, but I couldn't get the percentage of chats that were within that ideal period.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(c.id) AS 'Total'
FROM lh_chat as c
    LEFT JOIN lh_departament as d ON c.dep_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN lh_users u ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time-10800, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
    AND u.id != 178
    AND c.`status` <> 0
    AND c.dep_id IN (7,19,23)
    AND c.wait_time > 30
```

I was only able to add the number of chats above the ideal time, but not to make the percentage of chats that are within the expected range

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(c.wait_time > 30,  0, 1) * 1.0 / COUNT(c.id)
FROM lh_chat as c
    LEFT JOIN lh_departament as d ON c.dep_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN lh_users u ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time-10800, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
    AND u.id != 178
    AND c.`status` <> 0
```

The idea is to count only wait_times less then 30 seconds using SUM and then divide to the total count.
AND c.dep_id IN (7,19,23)